# Primary Key used as foreign key in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 2, how can we find out that certain primary key in one table is used as foreign key in another table. Like I have a table punching_informations having 'id' as primary key. I want to find out that whether an 'id' from punching_informations table is used as foreign key in another table named punching_request. PunchingInformation has one PunchingRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally there should be a `punching_information_id` in your `punching_request` table.
In that case your `punching_request.rb` model will have following line.

```
belongs_to :punching_information
```

However you can change this by using the element `:foreign_key` like following

```
belongs_to :punching_information, foreign_key: "some_new_id"
```